# ARKit+Xcode:Module compiled with Swift 5.0.1 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3.2 compiler:

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

I am trying to build an AR app with ARKit, trying to run these open-source ARKit project and Plugins on github:
https://github.com/augmentedrealityplugin/shapeDetection
https://github.com/ShawnMa16/AR-Drawing

However I have this problem

[image]

I have tried the solutions:

- 1. Set 'Yes' in Build Libraries for Distribution
     [image]
- 2. installing the Xcode Toolchain
     [image]
- 3. delete and add the framework again in Embedded Frameworks
     [image]

But it cannot help, is there any solutions to my problem, so I can at least try and run these project and Plugins on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Swift obtained ABI compatibility in v5.0. But only gained module compatibility in v5.1. So, frameworks compiled with a version before 5.1 are toolchain specific. This is what what the compatibility error you’re receiving refers to.

Pre 5.1, you need to compile both your application and the library with the same version of the Swift compiler. With 5.1 and beyond, preferably, use the latest toolchain for both, but that is optional as long as they are at least compiled with 5.1 or greater. Existing binary distributions of the library compiled pre v5.1 will not work with the latest version of Xcode.

This means you’ll need to compile the library from source, upgrading the Xcode project settings to at least 5.1, and possibly the source code, as necessary.

See this post for more details: https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/